# How was Washington and Jefferson's relationship in Dec 1799?

Tags: 18th-century, president

Bottom Line Up Front(BLUF)
***George Washington died December 14th, 1799. 
My question is what are some examples that demonstrate this period when these two preeminent founding fathers were bitter enemies.   Either examples which account for it,  or which demonstrate it. or even refute it***  ( my research is given below ).

Much has been written over the discordant vision for the United States and personal animosity between Thomas Jefferson and Alexander Hamilton.  Much less has been written about the similar relationship between George Washington and Thomas Jefferson.  George Washington the father of the country with his pragmatic military and political leadership; and Thomas Jefferson the idealistic visionary, primary author of the Declaration of Independence in his early 30's, who would ultimately come to oppose Washington.

It’s difficult to say today which was the most influential.  The country owed it’s early existence to Washington and not just because of his military achievements.  Washington who’s resignation as commander of the armies [stunned aristocratic Europe](http://wifeinthewildblueyonder.com/george-washington-resigns-as-commander-in-chief/) and may have been his greatest act. Washington’s who’s doctrine on foreign policy (Isolationism) as outlined in his farewell address was still in practical application 140 years after his death[*4].  The kind of country we are can be directly traced back to decisions made during his administration on trade, banking, taxation, peaceful transition of power, and tariffs.   More than any other man he’s arguable [responsible for the US Constitution](http://www.mountvernon.org/digital-encyclopedia/article/constitutional-convention/) and the [the office of the Presidency we know today](https://www.gilderlehrman.org/history-by-era/early-republic/essays/george-washington-and-constitution).

Thomas Jefferson’s influence was also profound.  His distrust of government encoded into law as  checks and balances,  explains our government structure,  different terms for different offices,  strong legislature, Bill of Rights, especially religious and press freedoms,  all came from Jefferson.   If not directly then his influence on men who were his political protégée’s.  Mason, Madison, and Monroe.  Thomas Jefferson more than any other founding father had a vision for the United States which would make it new and unique in history.  After Jefferson’s eight years in office,  his protégée’s (Madison, and Monroe) would control the Presidency for the next 16 years.  What the United States became is an emulsion of Washington and Jefferson’s visions.   These two men of diverse backgrounds and temperament, who’s relationship traversed friendship, distant collaborators, and political enemies.  In that order.

## Their backgrounds were diverse.

Both were tall, slave holding owners of great plantations.  Both were drawn to politics, and both were from Virginia. However both would come to there successes through different routes.

[Washington would lose his father at the age of 11](http://www.notablebiographies.com/Tu-We/Washington-George.html).  Being the third son, ([first son of his father’s second wife](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/biography/?gclid=CjwKCAiAo9_QBRACEiwASknDwcljkPfaW2dD12SPFxM3FLF7qzpj7Ck6xciXmKrp7_WbtcIgbo7nYBoC2foQAvD_BwE)),  George did not inherit a significant income or lands from his father, they went to his older Brother.  [Washington was the least educated Founding father](http://www.georgewashington.org/education.jsp) who was often scorned for his lack of education.  Washington’s formal education ended in the fourth grade (age 11).  After that he was largely self taught.  Washington spoke no foreign languages, and only traveled outside of the continental United States once (Caribbean).  Washington was employed as a surveyors assistant at the age of 15.  He would be appointed the county surveyor of the frontier Virginia Culpepper County at age 16.  He would pursue more than 150 professional engagements  surveying boundaries by the age of 21, in the vast Virginia, and Ohio territories (Kentucky was still part of Virginia when Washington was a surveyor).   Washington received a military commission at the age of 21 in the British Army (full time Virginia Militia,  not to be confused with the Regulars or part time militias)… achieving the rank of ([lieutenant colonel before he resigned](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/british-soldier-george-washington-experiences-combat-for-first-time)).  George Washington [become a household name in Europe (see #3)](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/french-indian-war/ten-facts-about-george-washington-and-the-french-indian-war/)  before the American Revolution for his exploits during the French and Indian war.

Thomas Jefferson was the eldest son of a [significant land owner in Virginia](https://www.monticello.org/site/jefferson/peter-jefferson).   Jefferson’s father died when he was 14, leaving him a wealthy income and lands which would become his plantation Monticello.   Jefferson had twelve years of formal education before entering University.  He attended William and Mary University for seven years,  continuing his studies in law after his first course of studies had completed.  Jefferson had a voracious appetite for books and learning all his life.  He was fluent in Greek, Latin, and French,  and would travel widely outside the United States prior to becoming Secretary of State and then the third President.

Both men served together in the Virginian Legislature, and the Continental Congress prior to the Revolutionary War.
Their war time experiences would kept them in geographic isolation from each other, both in important offices.    Washington was busy training, feeding, housing and fighting with the army which would eventually defeat the most powerful military in the world.   Jefferson would serve two terms as Governor of Virginia during the revolutionary war.

## Political Opponents

After the war  their orbits would intersect and they would begin to oppose each other on key issues.

- **[Shay’s rebellion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shays%27_Rebellion)**  Washington would oppose it.  He would appoint the commander and  send troops to put down the New England rebellion.  Jefferson would oppose the suppression of the rebellion by federal troops.   Jefferson’s famous quote, “The tree of liberty must be refreshed from time to time with the blood of patriots and tyrants.” November 13, 1787.   Jefferson would make that quote about Shay’s rebellion.
- **A standing Army**  Washington believed the nation needed a professional military.  Jefferson, who always distrusted government power, opposed a standing army.

  > > ”[Nor is it conceived needful or safe that a standing army should be kept up in 
  > >     time of peace for](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZTIoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=Nor+is+it+conceived+needful+or+safe+that+a+standing+army+should+be+kept+up+in+time+of+peace&source=bl) [defense against invasion]." –– Thomas Jefferson:
  > >
  > > The Jeffersonian Cyclopedia: A Comprehensive Collection of the Views of Thomas Jefferson Classified and Arranged in Alphabetical Order Under Nine Thousand Titles Relating to Government, Politics, Law, Education, Political Economy, Finance, Science, Art, Literature, Religious Freedom, Morals ( see item 518 "Army Reduction" )
- **The United States Constitution.**   Washington would chair the ratification convention and be the Constitutions highest profile supporter and signatory.  Jefferson serving the US in Paris at the time would be one of the most prominent [opponents (anti Federalists) of the US constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Federalism),  would influence delegates by writing letters opposing the ratification and criticizing the Constitution.
- **The office of the President**.   Washington would work with James Madison to create the office of the Presidency.   Jefferson believed all power should be rested in the legislature and would [oppose creating an Executive branch of Government for fear it would lead to monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Federalism).
- **Jay’s Treaty**  or “[the Treaty of Amity Commerce](http://www.mountvernon.org/digital-encyclopedia/article/jay-treaty/)”,  horrified Jefferson and his supporters.   Jefferson who openly favored the French, and feared both falling into a British orbit, and a new Monarchy (or Monarchical powers) sprinting up in the United States.   Jay’s Treaty lite all his lights.  The Treaty favored England both economically and militarily over France.    It allowed concessions which impinged upon American Neutrality.  It continued to allow British impressment of American sailors.  All and all it was a pretty one sided treaty with only one redeeming quality, it kept us out of war with Britain.   Washington ratified it unconditionally on this basis.  Jefferson strongly felt Washington –– in negotiating the treaty in secret, and keeping the terms of the treaty secret through the ratification process ––  had over stepped his authority and was moving the country further away from France and closer to monarchy.

**So this is where their relationship arch which spanned friends, colleagues, and political opponents would begin to lean towards personal enemies.  What are some of the events which demonstrate this animosity or account for the further deterioration of their admiration for one another.**

(see my answer below)

---

*3: Gordon Wood, The Radicalism of the American Revolution (1992), pp 105–06; 
Edmund Morgan, The Genius of George Washington (1980), pp 12–13; Sarah J. Purcell, Sealed With Blood: War, Sacrifice, and Memory in Revolutionary America (2002) p. 97; Don Higginbotham, George Washington (2004); Ellis, 2004
*4:”Washington's Farewell Address: A Foreign Policy of Independence", The American Historical Review 1934 Oxford University Press

Comment: In his [will](http://www.mountvernon.org/download/?file=http://s3.amazonaws.com/mtv-main-assets/files/modules/primary-sources/downloads/george-washingtons-last-will-and-testament-july-9--2.zip) (download link), Washington simply stated "... it is my express desire that my Corpse may be Interred in a private manner, without parade, or funeral Oration."

Comment: Downvote because it makes assertations about Washington leaving specific instructions, without supplying any documentation for the source.  Also because it reads much more like someone trying to expound a private theory than a question.  Indeed, the only question, seemingly tacked on as an afterthought, asks us if we can find evidence.

Comment: @MattSebastian When you say "in-house historian", do you mean that you were told the story by Mount Vernon's Research Historian, Mary Thomson, or just that you heard it from one of the tour-guides at Mount Vernon (who are often not actually historians)?

Answer (score 1):

## Personal Attacks

Washington’s and Jefferson’s political views were diverging through the time the US Constitution was being ratified Sept 1887 - June 1788, but after Jefferson accepted a position (Secretary of State) in the Washington Administration(March 22, 1790 – December 31, 1793) their discord would become personal, even to the point of being considered Treason (*).

(*)At the time neither Alexander Hamilton's Federalists nor Jefferson's Republican Democrats favored a loyal opposition two party system which we have today. [Working inside of the government,  to sabotage the government was widely seen by Federalists including George Washington as Treason](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-first-president/washington-jefferson-madison/), giving aid and comfort the nation's enemies.

- Initially installed as the First President George Washington was a very popular figure. Jefferson thus was reluctant to challenge him directly, and would first take aim at his ministers.
  [As Thomas Jefferson wrote privately to James Madison](http://www.mountvernon.org/digital-encyclopedia/article/press-attacks/), his close confidant, “the President, tho’ an honest man himself, may be circumvented by snares and artifices, and is in fact surrounded by men who wish to clothe the Executive in more than constitutional power.”
- In 1793 Britain and France were at war again.  Washington influenced by Alexander Hamilton pursued ed a neutrality policy in this war which ["infuriated Jefferson"](https://www.biography.com/us-president/george-washington). Thomas Jefferson believed the US should honor it's commitments to France Monarchy, even though the Monarchy had been replaced now by the French Republic. Washington sent John Jay to Britain to negotiate America's neutrality resulting in the **[John Jay's Treaty](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1784-1800/jay-treaty)**.
- [The popular press exploded from under fifty newspapers around 1776 to over 250 by 1800](http://www.mountvernon.org/digital-encyclopedia/article/press-attacks/)  Jefferson would both promote this growth and use these papers to attack and harass Washington,  both during his administration and continuing through his retirement.
- By [the end of 1792, there was a recognizable opposition party, centered around Thomas Jefferson;](http://www.mountvernon.org/digital-encyclopedia/article/press-attacks/) newspapers gave this party one of their strongest means of critiquing the Washington Administration. Although Jefferson denied it publicly at the time, Jefferson was a key figure behind the scenes in establishing the national opposition presses.
- In April 1796, [Jefferson wrote to a friend in Italy](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-first-president/washington-jefferson-madison/), bemoaning the state of American politics. “In place of that noble love of liberty and republican government which carried us triumphantly thro’ the war,” Jefferson wrote, “an Anglican, monarchical and aristocratical party has sprung up,” hoping to impose on the U.S. a government more British than American. “It would give you a fever,” he went on, “were I to name to you the apostates who have gone over to these heresies, men who [were] Samsons in the field and Solomons in the council, but who have had their heads shorn by the harlot England.” This letter became public and Washington and his supporters believed Jefferson was talking about Washington.
- [Jefferson helped James Monroe research his View of the Conduct of the Executive in the Foreign Affairs of the United States, published in 1797.](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-first-president/washington-jefferson-madison/) As Washington’s minister to France, Monroe had been recalled for insufficiently defending administration policy, and this book, defending his own conduct, was highly critical of Washington’s foreign policy.  Monroe had been the ambassador to France during the negotiation and ratification of Jay's treaty, which they saw as a betrayal. Monroe had advised the French that if they didn't like Washington's treaty, they just had to wait until the election and he would be removed from authority.  Oddly, Monroe the 5th president would become known for the Monroe Doctrine,  a doctrine of isolation and independence from European powers.

Jefferson would use his government position inside the Washington cabinet,  to create, organize, and fund opposition to Washington’s administration.

- [Two years prior to Thomas Jefferson’s resignation](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-first-president/washington-jefferson-madison/) from the Washington Administration, Jefferson put Philip Freneau on the State Department payroll as an interpreter. Freneau only spoke one foreign language, French, a language Jefferson was already fluent in. In parallel Jefferson installed Freneau as editor of the National Gazette, a national venue which Freneau would use, subsidized by State Dept money, to blast the Washington Administration. There Freneau campaigned against the administration Jefferson still served, which struck critics—Washington among them—as disloyal, and even treasonous. The Freneau/Jefferson, financial relationship becoming apparent to Washington,  is sited as one of the reason’s for Jefferson’s resignation from the State Dept.
- In the years after George Washington had left the Presidency(1797),  [he had severed all ties with Thomas Jefferson](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-first-president/washington-jefferson-madison/) .
- [By the end of Washington’s life](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-first-president/washington-jefferson-madison/) he had come to see Madison and Monroe as little more than pawns of Jefferson in a struggle over the country’s future and would become noticeable agitated at the mention of their names.
- Two years after George Washington's death in 1801, Jefferson would visit Mount Vernon(Washington's home) to pay his respects, Mrs. Washington would recall his appearance as “the most painful” occurrence of her life, “next to the loss of her husband.”
- [just before her death in 1802,](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-first-president/washington-jefferson-madison/) and three years after Washington's Death, Martha Washington called Jefferson “most detestable” and his election to the presidency two years earlier as “the greatest misfortune our country had ever experienced.”

*3: Gordon Wood, The Radicalism of the American Revolution (1992), pp 105–06;
Edmund Morgan, The Genius of George Washington (1980), pp 12–13; Sarah J. Purcell, Sealed With Blood: War, Sacrifice, and Memory in Revolutionary America (2002) p. 97; Don Higginbotham, George Washington (2004); Ellis, 2004
*4:”Washington's Farewell Address: A Foreign Policy of Independence", The American Historical Review 1934 Oxford University Press